# Why is it difficult to sample from a multivariate distribution?

Tags: random-generation, multivariate-distribution

The Monte Carlo Markov Chain method requires sampling from a multivariate distribution. This is because the Markov Chain process requires dependent draws. See 1:55 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LB1VHp4tLE. It is claimed that it is difficult to simultaneously draw from a multivariate distribution. But modern computers and software can sample from a multivariate distribution. So my first question is in which sense is it difficult? Because that is why a solution is proposed which is to sample from a conditional distribution. There is no need to watch the entire video because my question is only about sampling from a multivariate distribution. Why is it difficult to sample from a multivariate distribution as compared to a univariate distribution?

Comment: It's not--this is a false generalization.  Indeed, what do you really mean by "difficult"--in what sense?

Comment: In the sense of what is explained in the video. Because simultaneous sampling is difficult, as it is claimed, sampling is done from the conditional distribution and accordingly the Gibbs sampling is explained.

Comment: Difficulty is curse of dimensionally. [sampling from n-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Sampling)

Comment: Most people will not want to spend the time to watch a video to understand what your question might be.  Please include an explanation in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks @msuzen. This helps a lot. If I understand it correctly from the suggested link on the curse of dimensionality, as the dimension of the multivariate distribution increases, the number of points one needs to sample increases exponentially. This means that, to have a plausible sample that is representative of the underlying (multivariate) distribution, a lot of points need to be drawn from the underlying multivariate distribution.

Comment: Modern software and computers, such as the mvnrnd command of MATLAB, seems to be able to handle this, but I guess the problem is not only about sampling many points, but to also to use them in the calculation in an associated problem such as the MCMC so that instead other sampling methods, such as the Gibbs sampling, are used. Please correct me if these interpretations of mine have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @whuber. I developed the question with respect to the stated concerns. I hope this helps.

Comment: There are three ongoing problems with the question.  The first is that "difficult" has no definite meaning.  The second is that "multivariate distribution" covers a lot of ground, allowing for any general statements to be true or false depending on the details.  The third is that you are leaping, without justification, from a vague statement to one that is false (namely, that it is at problematic in any way to sample from bivariate Normal distributions or even multivariate Normal distributions generally).

Comment: Thanks @whuber for pointing out the problems with my question. In which sense it is difficult was indeed my question because modern computers and software can handle that. Now I edited the question that this is indeed my question. I hope this also addresses the two other problems you point out. If not, I would appreciate a further warning.

Comment: Thank you for making those improvements.  I still question your final question about bivariate Normal distributions, because they provide examples of dependent random variables where it is easy--conceptually and computationally--to draw values all at once without going through the sequence of conditional distributions.

Comment: Well, thanks for spending the time to help to improve the question. I edited the question further, dropping the part on bivariate distribution.

Comment: I do not understand this. I was asked to clarify the question and I did and I was thanked for it. I also said that I am willing to edit the question further. Closing the question without telling further how the question could be clarified is not acceptable. I request a reevaluation of the decision to close. This is not ok.

Comment: I request an explanation of the close decision. I object to the decision. I need an answer to my question and no answer is affecting my work.